# Jquery Inewsticker Pause on Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add news ticker in my website. Actually it loads perfect and working great. But when i hover on scrolling (slide) it doesn't stops, it was moving on.

Actually i need to stop when hovering the mouse on scrolling (slide). Could any one help me with this part.

My HTML code is,

```
<ul class="slide">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum 2</li>
    <li>I am designer</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

My Javascript is,

```
$('.slide').inewsticker({
    speed       : 2500,
    effect      : 'slide',
    dir         : 'ltr',
    font_size   : 13,
    color       : '#fff',
    font_family : 'arial',
    delay_after : 1000                      
});
```

Comment: according the the documentation there is no option to pause on hover https://github.com/progpars/inewsticker   using http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/index.html offers pause on hover

Comment: Thank you Pindo, i will go with the alternative one you gave..

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$('.slide').mouseenter(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

The JQuery plugin does not provide a way to do this.
You will have to modify the *inewsticker* script and get a handle to the timer it starts, the explicitly clear the timer that slides the texts.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b0vctm5e/) where the scrolling stops when you hover it.

Note that it 'stops' the sliding, it does not 'pauses' it.

Comment: Hi Ahs, actually when hovering it stops sliding, but after that the slider is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I checked that plugin you used that have limited options so you have to modify inewsticker.js

I would like to suggest you to use http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/index.html this plugin. Really I like it very easy to integrate.